# JS Сортировка данных по алфавиту

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка, объекты

Как отсортировать это по name по алфавиту?  Делаю так и это не работает.

```
        var views_new = {};
        Object.values(views)
          .sort(function(a, b) {
                var x = a.name;
                var y = b.name;
                return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
            }).forEach(function(v, i) {
              views_new[v.handle] = v;
           });
```

Использую это.

```
 {
  "row-content": {
    "handle": "row-content",
    "name": "Content",
    "isSubItem": true,
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "core",
      "content": "row",
      "group": "advanced",
      "category": "row-content",
      "categorized": true
    }
  },
  "undefined": {
    "type": "separator"
  },
  "columns": {
    "handle": "columns",
    "name": "Columns",
    "query": {
      "kind": "colGroup"
    },
    "templateName": "fl-content-panel-col-groups-view"
  },
  "pp-services": {
    "handle": "pp-services",
    "name": "Products",
    "isSubItem": true,
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "core",
      "content": "row",
      "group": "powerpacktemplates",
      "category": "pp-services",
      "categorized": true
    }
  },
  "pp-subscribe-forms": {
    "handle": "pp-subscribe-forms",
    "name": "Subscribe Forms",
    "isSubItem": true,
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "core",
      "content": "row",
      "group": "powerpacktemplates",
      "category": "pp-subscribe-forms",
      "categorized": true
    }
  },
  "pp-team": {
    "handle": "pp-team",
    "name": "Team",
    "isSubItem": true,
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "core",
      "content": "row",
      "group": "powerpacktemplates",
      "category": "pp-team",
      "categorized": true
    }
  },
  "pp-testimonials": {
    "handle": "pp-testimonials",
    "name": "Testimonials",
    "isSubItem": true,
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "core",
      "content": "row",
      "group": "powerpacktemplates",
      "category": "pp-testimonials",
      "categorized": true
    }
  },
  "row-call-to-action": {
    "handle": "row-call-to-action",
    "name": "Call to Action",
    "isSubItem": true,
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "core",
      "content": "row",
      "group": "advanced",
      "category": "row-call-to-action",
      "categorized": true
    }
  },
  "savedRows": {
    "handle": "savedRows",
    "name": "*Saved Rows",
    "templateName": "fl-content-panel-saved-rows",
    "query": {
      "kind": "template",
      "type": "user",
      "content": "row",
      "categorized": false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал пример, надеюсь то, что нужно.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jcsokp?file=index.js

- Использовал localCompare вместо обычного сравнения строк. Флаг ignorePunctuation, который говорит сам за себя, проигнорирует знаки пунктуации при сравнении строк. Иначе строка с * будет некорректно сравненна.
- Приводил сравниваемые строки в lowerCase.
- Поставил проверку на undefined. В противном случае, в результате будет ключ undefined.

Comment: 1. Код должен быть в ответе, а не неизвестно где. 2. `localeCompare` - жуткий тормоз. В IE время выполнения сортировки может увеличиться с 0.035 секунды до 54 секунд. 3. В вопросе проблема не в сортировке.

Comment: 1. Ссылку поправил, спасибо :)
2. На счет тормозов - я посмотрю тесты, но при сравнении строк с символами их прийдется убирать, для корректного результата.
3. "Как отсортировать это по name по алфавиту?" - спрашивали про сортировку.

Comment: 1. скопируй код в ответ. 2. там сборка мусора зажирается. 3. ну и что? 4. не вижу работающего кода.